# How to update the cursor when I use mousewheel?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sprite, sfml

My problem is that when I move the view with the mousewheel, **the cursor sprite
stays behind and it doesn't update to the cursor itself**, how do I fix this?

***Main Game Loop:***

```
this->cursor->Update(window);

if (event->type == sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved)
{
    if (event->mouseWheel.delta == 1)
    {
        this->view->move(sf::Vector2f(0, -25));
        window->setView(*this->view);
        event->mouseWheel.delta = 0;
    }
    else if (event->mouseWheel.delta == -1)
    {
        this->view->move(sf::Vector2f(0, 25));
        window->setView(*this->view);
        event->mouseWheel.delta = 0;
    }
}
```

***Cursor Update Function:***

```
this->setPosition(static_cast<sf::Vector2f>(sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window)));
```

***Github Link:***
[Capitalist Adventure - Project In Question](https://github.com/spitz123321/Capitalist-Adventure)

Comment: I have the mouse cursor hidden so the cursor sprite looks like the cursor so thats not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the SFML Forums I have found an answer to why the set sprite position function wasn't setting my sprite cursor to my mouse.The reason was that the sf::View messes around with the coordinates on-screen.

**Answer:**

```
this->setPosition(window->mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window)));
```